# How can i do duplex communication between and android application and and esp32 over Wifi Aware

Tags: java, android, nodemcu, esp-idf, esp8266wifi

While trying to communicate between android and nodemcu using Wifi Aware libraries of the respective sdks, `android.net.wifi.aware` for android SDK and `esp_nan` for the nodemcu, i am unable to figure out any way to receive the data sent by the android app via the `SubscribeDiscoverySession.sendMessage` method on the nodemcu side

The NodeMCU is acting as the publisher and the Android app is acting as the subscriber.

My question is at this point,iss receiving data on the nodeMCU side over wifi Aware even possible?

Is there any other protocol except wifi aware that nodeMCU and Android phones support that will allow me to do p2p without purchasing any more hardware?

- Investigated the esp_nan library, Could have missed something there but i doubt it
- Put some decent effort into trying to understand how the sendMesaage method works
- Investigated the possible use of regular wifi, unfortunately, creating a wifi network and connecting to it is not feasible as the android phone needs to have internet working.
- Investigated using Wifi Direct, as far as i understand, esp-idf does not support it

I would like to avoid turning on the hotspot of the mobile, as then, either i would need to hardcode the hotspot SSID and password into both the nodemcu and the App, or have some way of sending these to the nodemcu, which makes us go back to square one.

Comment: Let your Android phone be a hotspot for the esp.